# Is the JavaScript keyword `with` really deprecated?

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript `with` statements have for a long time been considered bad coding practice, and been advised against.

[This page](http://2ality.com/2011/06/with-statement.html) indicates that `with` is deprecated and will throw an error in strict mode, my browser throws an error when using `with` in strict mode, and Google Closure Compiler throws an error indicating that strict mode does not allow `with`:

```
JSC_USE_OF_WITH: The with statement cannot be used in strict mode.
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with), it is recommended to avoid using `with`, but as of today, it [does not appear to be actually deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features), and [it does not appear to be included in examples of code restrictions of strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

This appears somewhat contradicting and confusing. So, is `with` really deprecated or not?

Comment: The last link does include `with`, and the first MDN link clearly says that it's not allowed in strict mode. The middle MDN link omits it but it seems to be an incomplete list anyway. (MDN is a wiki, not a specification.)

Comment: I do not think it was actually ever drepecated other that banning its use from within strict mode. In the end there is really no reason to use with.

Comment: @JJJ, I missed the statement in the MDN link where it says that it is not allowed in strict mode, thanks for pointing that out. Why don't you provide it as an answer?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Simplifying_variable_uses

Comment: Soooo… it is clearly not supported in strict mode, which is kind of the "we should all be doing it this way in the future mode", and a compiler throws an error… I'm not sure how much more consensus on "deprecated" you need?! At least "soft deprecation" fits?!

Comment: I guess as @deceze is saying, any `statement` that raises an error in "strict mode" is deprecated.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165234/discussion-on-question-by-tomas-langkaas-is-the-javascript-keyword-with-really).

Comment: @epascarello with is very useful for templating languages! It's used in Vue.js to inject variables into expressions the user defines in the html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This official stance by the TC39 group (the guys that publish the ECMAScript specification) is insightful:

> ### Why don't we deprecate features?
>
> Deprecation doesn't work on the web. Since we [can't remove bad features](http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/about/faq/#breaking), a developer has little incentive to stop using a feature just because somebody somewhere doesn't like it. Labeling features "deprecated" without ever removing them is pointless.
>
> http://tc39wiki.calculist.org/about/faq/#deprecate

So, it will probably never be officially deprecated by the ECMAScript standard; however, within the community the consensus that `with` is bad is strong enough that the big players (i.e. the compiler and engine implementers) have opted to treat it as deprecated if you opt into strict mode and/or opt to use certain strict compilers.

Comment: «the big players ... have opted to treat it as deprecated if you opt into strict mode» — actually, it's not an option. The `with` statement is invalid in strict mode by specification. The players have generally opted to not optimize (or to de-optimize) functions containing a `with` statement.