# Alternative to JavaScript `with` statement when generating DOM elements

Tags: javascript, scope, with-statement

Say, I have a JavaScript library to produce a DOM fragment like the following

```
<main>
  <h1>A heading</h1>
  <p>A paragraph</p>
</main>
```

where the library, `domlib`, has methods for any type of element, and a function generating the fragment above could look like this:

```
function(domlib){
  return domlib.main(
    domlib.h1('A heading'),
    domlib.p('A paragraph')
  );
}
```

Within this function I would rather like to call the `domlib` methods like this:

```
main(
  h1('A heading'),
  p('A paragraph')
)
```

To achieve this, I could place all the methods of `domlib` in the global scope, but I would rather avoid to pollute the global scope. To me, this appears to be a case where the `with` statement would have been an ideal solution:

```
function(domlib){
  with(domlib){
    return main(
      h1('A heading'),
      p('A paragraph')
    );
  }
}
```

Although still supported, [the `with` statement is practically deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48811296/6738706), and will [throw an error in strict mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48810592/6738706).

I do not see many other options, except to assign `domlib` methods to local function variables, but that would easily result in assigment of dozens of local variables, in which case the first approach (calling methods on `domlib` directly) would lead to simpler code.

My question is, *is there any other alternative to achieve what I want*, with similar simplicity and readability as using a `with` statement?

Comment: You might also consider using a special transpiler (like jsx) or a templating system of your liking.

Comment: @Bergi, good point, though I am really interested in how far you can get with JS alone.

Answer (score 9):

The method I would use is to explicitly list the elements I want via destructuring.

For example, in your case I would have something like this:

```
const component = ({main, h1, p}) => main(
  h1('A heading'),
  p('A paragraph')
);
```

This is similar to doing

```
const component = (domlib) => {
  const {main, h1, p} = domlib;
  return main(
    h1('A heading'),
    p('A paragraph')
  );
};
```

Comment: this is cool. Didn't know the deconstructor could be used as a parameter. Definitely an upvote!

Comment: @smnbbrv "destructuring expression"

Comment: Where can I find browser support info for javascript deconstructing?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with es6 quite easily :

```
const functionName = ({ main, h1, p }) => main(h1('heading'), p('paragraph'))
```

`functionName(domlib)`

But you will have difficulty cross browser as es6 is not fully supported

Comment: Not really, every major browser and a couple versions behind support 94% ES6 (https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/). For everything else theres transpiling, or even polyfills.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to redesign `domlib` so that it supports chaining in a way similar to

```
domlib
    .begin('main')
        .h1('A heading')
        .p('A paragraph')
    .end()
```

...but in a real-life code I'd rather replace `domlib` with `$` or `_` :

```
function($){
    return $.main(
       $.h1('A heading'),
       $.p('A paragraph')
    );
}
```

An overhead of two extra chars per call is a reasonable price for avoiding tricks and hacks.

Comment: `.end()` calls looks like a maintenance horror.

Comment: @Bergi: no more than `_.value` ;)

Comment: I had not thought about a chaining approach, nice suggestion. Though, I cannot see how that would support building a DOM tree of arbitrary depth.

Comment: @TomasLangkaas: the idea is that `begin` opens a container tag and `end` closes it, and you can nest them just like html tags. Of course, you can also use tag-specific  methods like `open_main` and `close_main` instead, in which case your JS matches HTML 1:1.