# javascript eval with multiple variables

Tags: javascript, variables, eval

I want to use eval to calculate the following string with multiple varaibles
I have all the variables stored in my object

```
let myVars = {
    a : 10,
    b : 20,
    c : 30,
}
let str = "a+b+c+10"
// how to evaluate the string ...
```

Comment: Can you please share what you've tried so far and what you're having trouble with?

Comment: This is not a use-case for `eval`, just use the properties in the object: `myVars.a + myVars.b + myVars.c + 10`

Comment: @Teemu OP has an arbitrary string, not a JavaScript expression.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, and can't find the answer on the internet

Comment: `I want to use eval to calculate the following string` What do you mean by this? What is the desired result?

Comment: That string has nothing to do with the given object.

Comment: @Teemu , this is just an example the string is random all the time..

Comment: @StudioTime, the strings are random all the time and I have values stored in an object , each time I want to calculate the value of string , in this case str = "a+b+c+10" therefore the result will be 70

Comment: What is the use-case? [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) is not usually the best practice.

Comment: @Teemu do you know how to do it the best way??

Comment: Maybe, but we need to know the exact use-case. Where is the string coming from? How is the object created, why are you needing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the (unknown) variables and use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (cave!) for getting a result.

```js
let
    values = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 },
    str = "a+b+c+10";

str = str.replace(/[a-z0-9_]+/g, s => values[s] ?? s);

console.log(eval(str));
```

Comment: This answer is unnecessarily complex (from my view). However, it is good to have another option. 

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question, but I will try my best to answer.

The `eval()` method will automatically get the variables from the global context. If you want to get the result, just save the result from the `eval()` function.

```js
// Object destructuring for easier readability
let { a, b, c } = {
  a : 10,
  b : 20,
  c : 30,
}
let str = "a + b + c + 10";

const total = eval(str);
console.log(total); // Should be: 70
```

The code above will return the result from the mathematical operation.

**However, you should [never use `eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!), as it can run any code arbitrarily.**

Comment: This will only work if the variables are always `a`, `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention that a+b+c... are for the myVars object so you have different ways:

```js
let myVars = {
    a : 10,
    b : 20,
    c : 30,
}
let str = "myVars.a+myVars.b+myVars.c+10"
console.log(eval(str))
```

Although I don't suggest this way to you because here we can use that without eval so that will be easier.

Another way is to use Regex:

```js
let myVars = {
    a : 10,
    b : 20,
    c : 30,
}
let str = "a+b+c+10"
const arrayName="myVars"
str=str.replace(/([a-z]+)/gi,arrayName+".$1")
console.log(eval(str))
```

Here you add the object name behind the variables dynamically with Regex.

Or simply you can do what you want without eval (If you want):

```js
let myVars = {
    a : 10,
    b : 20,
    c : 30,
}

let sum=Object.values(myVars).reduce((partialSum, a) => partialSum + a, 0) + 10;
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mathjs** library instead.

First download the library:

```
npm install mathjs
```

Import evaluate(), then simply use **evaluate(expression, scope)** like this:

```
let myVars = {
  a : 10,
  b : 20,
  c : 30,
}
let str = "a+b+c+10"
console.log(evaluate(str, myVars)) # Prints 70
```

Check the documentation for more examples: [mathjs](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html)

Answer (score -1):

While remembering that [Eval is Evil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/197769/51685) since it allows for arbitrary code execution, you *can* use [the `with` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) here to change the eval statement's global namespace:

```js
let myVars = {
  a: 10,
  b: 20,
  c: 30,
};
let str = "a+b+c+10";
let result = null;
with (myVars) {
  result = eval(str);
}
console.log(result); // logs 70
```

Again, I do not recommend using `eval`.

Comment: `eval` is not evil automatically, ([see also Shog9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/197823/1169519)). There's nothing `eval` can do what DevTools couldn't. The problems start if you'll send the eval'd (user input) content to your server, and then put it on pages anybody can visit.

Comment: the `with` statement was deprecated and not recommended already 10 years ago so your code doubles down on unrecommended code

Comment: @mplungjan Where did you find the information that it's deprecated? Sure, it's not recommended for multiple reasons, as the MDN page says, but there are no indications of deprecation.

Comment: Ok, it is in ALL INTENTS AND PURPOSES deprecated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810592/is-the-javascript-keyword-with-really-deprecated

Comment: The first thing MDN says on the `with` statement documentation is that it shouldn't be used! [See it here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with)